# how to get timezone

Tags: c++

i m new to c.I want to FTP to a system and get the timezone of that system.in c++

Comment: Nice question. Is there anything you already tried, or just want us to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the FTP standard to do this.  You could try uploading a new (small) file and check its date-time as reported by FTP, compared to current local time.

Answer (score 1):

New answer for old question.

Rationale for revisiting this:  We have better tools now.

This [free, open-source, portable library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) will get the current time zone setting in terms of the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  On Windows it will convert the Windows timezone into an [IANA time zone](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  [Fully documented](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

Here's how you print out the name of the current time zone:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::current_zone()->name() << '\n';
}
```

For me this currently outputs:

```
America/New_York
```

You can convert a `std::chrono::system_clock` to a local time and print it out:

```
std::cout << date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(),
                              std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
```

which just output for me:

```
2016-07-16 19:24:00.447015 EDT
```

See the [github wiki](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes) for many more examples.